# Very strange JS / jQuery behavior - alert() inclusion/exclusion

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I have the following table. In this table I have dynamically added rows of the following form:

```
<tr class="conditionalRow">
  <td class="logicalData">
    <select oldvalue="AND" class="logicSelectionMenu">          
      <option value="AND">AND</option>
      <option value="AND (">AND (</option>
      <option value="OR">OR </option>
      <option value="OR (">OR (</option>
      <option value=")">)</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td class="fieldData">
    <p>Other Data that you don't need to worry about</p>  
  </td>
  <td class="conditionData">
    <p>Other Data that you don't need to worry about</p>  
  </td>
  <td class="compareData">
    <p>Other Data that you don't need to worry about</p>  
  </td>
  <td>
   <button class="removeConditionButton" type="button"> - </button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I use the following jQuery selectors to handle the onchange events:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".logicSelectionMenu").change(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    updateLogicMenu(row);
  });
  $(".logicSelectionMenu").focus(function() {
    $(this).attr("oldValue",$(this).val());
  });
});

function updateLogicMenu(inRow) {
  var selectedVal = $(inRow).find(".logicSelectionMenu").attr("value");
  var oldVal = $(inRow).find(".logicSelectionMenu").attr("oldValue");

/* -=>  VERY IMPORTANT LINE BELOW!!!  <=- */
//  alert("Hi, I cause a time delay");

  if (selectedVal == ")") {
  // clears cell contents if ")" is choosen by user
    $(inRow).find(".fieldSelectionMenu"    ).css("visibility","hidden").html("");
    $(inRow).find(".conditionSelectionMenu").css("visibility","hidden").html("");    
    $(inRow).find(".compareData"           ).css("visibility","hidden").html("");
  }
  else if(oldVal == ")" || oldVal === undefined) {
  // regenerates cell contents when user changes selection from ")" to another
    alert("regenerating");
    $(inRow).find(".fieldSelectionMenu").css("visibility","visible").html(getFieldSelectionOptions());
    $(inRow).find(".conditionSelectionMenu").css("visibility","visible");    
    $(inRow).find(".compareSelectionMenu").css("visibility","visible");
    updateFieldMenu(inRow); // function regenerates the next cell contents
                            // and calls another function 
                            // which regenerates the next cell contents, 
                            // and chains on and on ... etc
  }
  else { ; } // no action is needed,no clearing or regeneration
}
```

The problem is that when I select the ")" option from the drop down menu and then select another option. the page does now behave as expected.

- When the very important line **IS NOT** commented out, both alert boxes pops up saying "I cause a time delay" and "regenerating" and the contents of the following cells get regenerated as expected.
- When the very important line **IS** commented out, the JavaScript does not enter the else clause and the content of the following cells are NOT regenerated.

What is causing this alert box to cause the page to behave as expected, but it's absence make the page behave unexpectedly? Is it the time delay of the user clicking the OK button? I do not want this alert box on the production page so how do I make the page behave the same way with or without the alert box?

Comment: Any chance of having a working version to have a look at? (e.g. jsfiddle)

Comment: A more descriptive question title would be preferable...

Comment: I hope you aren't using the select menu's value's as a SQL statement

Comment: Are you missing a `</tr>`, or is it just not shown in the code snippet? I could see issues with jQuery trying to find closest "tr" if the element is not closed.

Comment: I have the `</tr>` tag, I didn't copy and paste enough of the data

Comment: @RMP This is a page for internal company use so the chance of SQL injections are slim. Plus there is both client-side and server-side validation, thwarting a simple client-side page editing hack.

Comment: *for internal company use* ... Meet Mr. disgruntled soon-to-be-ex-employee ... Whoops, where's your important data now?

Comment: @vzwick You can't do a data dump through this web interface. Also, there is user validation. Also, the DB is a read-only, non-production copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to *ahren's* observation I have found a fix for my code.

***ahren's*** observation:

"The focus event fires again after selection is changed, and therefore oldVal is updated. Having the alert() removes this focus and prevents it from firing again"

**The Fix:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".logicSelectionMenu").change(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    updateLogicMenu(row);
  });

/* DON'T USE onfocus event
   to set the oldValue
  $(".logicSelectionMenu").focus(function() {
    $(this).attr("oldValue",$(this).val());
  });
*/

});

function updateLogicMenu(inRow) {
  var selectedVal = $(inRow).find(".logicSelectionMenu").attr("value");
  var oldVal = $(inRow).find(".logicSelectionMenu").attr("data-oldValue");

/* -=>  VERY IMPORTANT LINE BELOW!!!  <=- */
//  alert("Hi, I cause a time delay");

  if (selectedVal == ")") {
  // clears cell contents if ")" is choosen by user
    $(inRow).find(".fieldSelectionMenu"    ).css("visibility","hidden").html("");
    $(inRow).find(".conditionSelectionMenu").css("visibility","hidden").html("");    
    $(inRow).find(".compareData"           ).css("visibility","hidden").html("");
  }
  else if(oldVal == ")" || oldVal === undefined) {
  // regenerates cell contents when user changes selection from ")" to another
    alert("regenerating");
    $(inRow).find(".fieldSelectionMenu"    ).css("visibility","visible").html(getFieldSelectionOptions());
    $(inRow).find(".conditionSelectionMenu").css("visibility","visible");    
    $(inRow).find(".compareSelectionMenu"  ).css("visibility","visible");
    updateFieldMenu(inRow); // function regenerates the next cell contents
                            // and calls another function 
                            // which regenerates the next cell contents, 
                            // and chains on and on ... etc
  }
  else { ; } // no action is needed,no clearing or regeneration

  /* SET THE VALUE HERE: */
  $(inRow).find(".logicSelectionMenu").attr("data-oldValue",selectedVal);
}
```

Set the value of `oldValue` at the end of the function and let `oldVal === undefined` catch the first pass through the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectedVal = $(inRow).find(".logicSelectionMenu").attr("value");
```

`.logicSelectionMenu` doesn't have an attribute `value`.

Use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val) instead:

```
var selectedVal = $(inRow).find(".logicSelectionMenu").val();
```

Also, as a side note, you're invalidating your HTML by having an attribute called `oldvalue`, you should use the `data-*` attributes, and set it like: `data-oldvalue="oldvalue"`.

And the way you're doing it now, you're accessing `attr("oldValue")` when you set `oldvalue="val"` - **note the case**.

`oldVal` is never `undefined` as you've set it in your markup, so the `||` portion of your `if` statement is redundant.

Comment: While that may be true it doesn't explain why inclusion/exclusion of the commented line effects the way the page functions

Comment: Thanks for the `data-*` validation tip. I have corrected that and noted it for future use. `oldVal` _was_ undefined when the page dynamically added the `<tr>` for the `first` onchange event. However I suspect the problem as something to do with the time delay of the user clicking the alert box that causes the page to function correctly/incorrectly based on the alertbox's inclusion/exclusion respectively. **Why the time delay matters** is what is stumping me.

Comment: @awashburn - After much thought, I've figured it out ;-) The `focus` event fires twice if the `alert()` is included, as `focus` is removed and then added again. So it's not the "time" delay at all, it's more the fact that `oldVal` gets updated again after the alert box is closed.